# unsupported packages handling in TeX4HT

Tags: tex4ht

In `tralics` http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/tralics/ it's possible to handles any `unknown commands` from `unsupported package` such as like `hyperref.sty`, for example, by including an `<error>` in the converted XML tag.

**Example:**
 <error n='\hypersetup' l='35' c='Undefined command'/>

So, apparently it should never fail to parse the document as long as it is valid LaTeX. How do get the same facility in our `TeX4HT`??? This major work is required in our `TeX4HT` for non missing any content in our final output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no unknown commands in `tex4ht`. LaTeX is used for compilation, so all commands are supported. When you get compilation error, it is usually because the configuration was written for the older version of package and it should be updated, the other issue is when some third-party package is modifying some command which is modified also by `tex4ht`.